# avatar not being displayed json encode

Tags: php, jquery

As soon as i added `.$thedatabase->displayavatar($username1,2).` nothing is being displayed.  It isn't a jQuery problem, so i haven't included that code.  Why is it when i add that code nothing is returned with json_encode?

leaderboard.php

```
$thedatabase = new Database();
$thedatabase->opendb();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getleader)) {
$username1 = $row['username'];
$rating = $row['rating'];


$username = str_replace(' ','-',$username1);

$leaderboard[] = "<div class='leaderboard-user'><ul><li>".$thedatabase->displayavatar($username1,2)."</li><li><a>$username1</a></li><li>$rating</li></ul></div>";
}
$thedatabase->closedb();

echo json_encode($leaderboard);
```

displayavatar function in Database class

```
echo "<a href='/user/$user'><img src='/test.png' width='70px' height='70px' /></a>";
```

Comment: You probably have an error that makes the script crash. Do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: i checked firebug no error.. here is the response ... i replaced my website url with test.com if your wondering. <a href='/user/testing'><img src='http://www.test.com/test.png' width='70px' height='70px' /></a>["<div class='close-button' data-type='leaderboard'><a>close<\/a><\/div><div id='leaderboard-title'>Stack Leaderboard<\/div>","<div class='leaderboard-user'><ul><li><\/li><li><a href='http:\/\/www.test.com\/user\/testing'>testing<\/a><\/li><li>4<\/li><\/ul><\/div>"]

Comment: Activate error reporting in PHP and look in Firebug what the response looks like

Comment: How are we supposed to know what your `Database` class looks like, and what the function `displayavatar()` does and accepts. Right now you are sending it the variable `$username1` AND the number `2` in the second argument, is that intended ?

Comment: yes that is intended.  The parameter is just the username and a condition for the height and width of the image.   '2' is for 70px

Comment: And you are sure you are getting the username from your SQL query, and that the result is not empty, and that the displayavatar() function is returning expected values etc. You will need to do some fault finding on your own, it's hard to point at something specifically wrong here.

Comment: yes i am getting the username, if i remove `.$thedatabase->displayavatar($username1,2).` and add `hello` then it returns `testing` and `4`.  Thanks for the help anyway.  If you look at the response above it is not being included in the list, rather outside the list.

Answer (score 0):

You're fetching the row

```
$username1 = $row['username'];
$rating = $row['rating'];
$username = str_replace(' ','-',$username1);
```

so your username is in $username, but for the funcion

```
$thedatabase->displayavatar($username1,2)
```

you are using the $username1, there's propably the empty char, and it can't make query

if it's not relevant for your query and there can be empty char, then sorry :))

Comment: $username is just hyperlinks, a dash between spaces... i think i'll have to store the image in a variable and then return the variable, rather than echo it.  thanks anyway

Comment: if you could show the $thedatabase->displayavatar function, maybe there's something..